# Error in latex: [3Broken pipe

Tags: beamer, xetex, errors

Yesterday, I compiled my LaTeX document in this computer and everything was fine. Then, I compiled the same document in another computer and again fine. Today, I tried to compile without doing any new modifications and the log stops at the message

```
[3Broken pipe
```

without finish the compilation. What could be wrong? I am attaching the log output.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasercs.sty)
Document Class: beamer 2011/09/12 development version 3.20 A class for typesett
ing presentations (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex))

(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.de
f
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df-via-dvi.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/xxcolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hxetex.

(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaserequires.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecompatibility.st
y) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasefont.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sansmathaccent/sansmathaccent.sty
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetranslator.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/translator-lang
uage-mappings.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemisc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetwoscreens.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseoverlay.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetitle.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasesection.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframe.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseverbatim.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframesize.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseframecomponents.
sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasecolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenotes.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetoc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetemplates.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaseboxes.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaselocalstructure.s
ty (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasenavigation.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasetheorems.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasethemes.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemede
fault.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/font/beamerfontthem
edefault.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/beamercolorth
emedefault.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/inner/beamerinnerth
emedefault.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterth
emedefault.sty))) (./presentation-cfg.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeFr
ankfurt.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/outer/beamerouterth
emesmoothbars.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/inner/beamerinnerth
emerounded.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/beamercolorth
emeorchid.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/color/beamercolorth
emewhale.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/font/beamerfontthem
eprofessionalfonts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eulervm/eulervm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/mathspec/mathspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty)
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 107.
*************************************************
) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica
* Neue'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica
* Neue'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica
* Neue/B'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica
* Neue/I'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica
* Neue/BI'.
*************************************************
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/mathrsfs.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/font/beamerfontthem
eserif.sty)
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Futura'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Futura'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Futura'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Futura'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Futura-Light'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Futura-Light'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica
* Neue'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica
* Neue'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica
* Neue/B'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica
* Neue/I'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica
* Neue/BI'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica Neue
* Light'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica Neue
* Light'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica Neue
* Light/B'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica Neue
* Light/I'.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "aat-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* AAT feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (21,0) not available in font 'Helvetica Neue
* Light/BI'.
*************************************************
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/polyglossia/gloss-english.ldf)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-natbib.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/verbose-note.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/authortitle.bbx
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/verbose-note.cbx)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)

Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported.

))) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)

Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.
(biblatex)                Footnote detection will not work.


Package biblatex Warning: 'babel' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
(biblatex)                Loading 'csquotes' recommended.

(./main.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./main.out) (./main.out)

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.


(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
r-basic-dictionary/translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
r-bibliography-dictionary/translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
r-environment-dictionary/translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
r-months-dictionary/translator-months-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
r-numbers-dictionary/translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
r-theorem-dictionary/translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict)

Package biblatex Warning: Data encoding is 'utf8'.
(biblatex)                Use backend=biber.

No file main.bbl.
No file main.nav.
[1]
No file main.toc.
[2]
** WARNING ** TrueType post table name index 65535 > 32767
** WARNING ** Invalid glyph name index number: 65535 (>= 280)
** WARNING ** Invalid version 2.0 'post' table
** ERROR ** Could not obtain necessary font info.

Output file removed.

No file main.toc.
[3Broken pipe
```

Comment: Did you try to delete all auxiliary files and recompile? The auxiliary files are files with names of the form `main.aux`, `main.toc`, `main.bbl`, `main.nav`, etc. Basically anything starting with `main` that you did not write yourself. (Please do make a backup if you're not sure what you're doing.)  Also, when posting a question please add four spaces before each verbatim line. I did this for you now, and you can see that the question is now easier to read.

Comment: The last Warning messages point to a problem with a TrueType font. So I guess you are using lualatex or xelatex to compile. Did you install/modify any of the system fonts? (in particular "Helvetica Neue", "Futura" or  "Futura-light")

Comment: Thanks to both of you.

Yori: yes, I did delete all main.* files except the .tex. I compiled again and it didn't work.

@JLDiaz: exactly. I installed a new typeface Futura-Light to use with XeLaTeX. As I told before, it was compiling yesterday with this new typeface. After the errors came out, I tried to remove the new typeface, erase the aux files and compile just to check if the problem was due to the typeface but I has the same problem and message.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the typeface and it is now working. Thanks everyone.